# Dynamic channels with Android and MQTT

Tags: android, mqtt

I am documenting on one topic that i am confused about. I am using MQTT with Android. I can successfully register clients and send messages to static channels. I created two channels, and subscribed a client to a channel, and the other one to another channel. Every channel receives the proper messages.
Very pleased with this.

Now I am trying to have dynamic channels, to know each client which id has and with which channel it's using.  I don't understand how to do that. When i "register" a client to the mosquitto broker i can subscribe to a "fake" channel (i understood that the broker creates that channel if it does not exist right?) but how can i know which client listens to which channel?
Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clear things up a bit - MQTT doesn't really have any concept of static or dynamic channels. If you publish or subscribe to a topic, or if a retained message exists for that topic then it exists, otherwise it doesn't.

The protocol doesn't provide any means for determining what clients are listening to which topics. You could implement this at the application level though. Detecting whether a client is connected or not can be done using the presence mechanism described here: http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/presence and you should be able to do something similar to determine what clients are subscribing to which topics.